# How to get the PC models with identical speed?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get pairs of PC models with identical speeds and the same RAM capacity. Each resulting pair should be displayed only once, i.e. (i, j) but not (j, i).

Result required as : model with the bigger number, model with the smaller number, speed, and RAM. The result I am expecting is

```
╔═══════╦═══════╦═══════╦═════╗
║ model ║ model ║ speed ║ ram ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═══════╬═════╣
║  1233 ║  1121 ║   750 ║ 128 ║
║  1233 ║  1232 ║   500 ║  64 ║
║  1260 ║  1232 ║   500 ║  32 ║
╚═══════╩═══════╩═══════╩═════╝
```

and table structure is

```
╔═══════╦═══════╦═════╗
║ model ║ speed ║ ram ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════╣
║  1121 ║   600 ║ 128 ║
║  1121 ║   600 ║ 128 ║
║  1121 ║   750 ║ 128 ║
║  1232 ║   450 ║  32 ║
║  1232 ║   450 ║  64 ║
║  1232 ║   500 ║  32 ║
║  1232 ║   500 ║  64 ║
║  1233 ║   500 ║  64 ║
║  1233 ║   750 ║ 128 ║
║  1233 ║   800 ║ 128 ║
║  1233 ║   900 ║ 128 ║
║  1260 ║   500 ║  32 ║
╚═══════╩═══════╩═════╝
```

The query I am trying is this and I am using MySQL

```
select pca.model, pcb.model, pca.speed, pca.ram 
from pc pca 
where pca.speed in (
    select pcb.speed 
    from pc pcb 
    where pca.speed = pcb.speed
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
select distinct 
  pca.model, pcb.model, pca.speed, pca.ram
from pc pca 
join pc pcb 
  on (pca.speed = pcb.speed 
  and pca.ram = pcb.ram 
  and pca.model > pcb.model)
```

Comment: almost there,  just one record repeating , the last row of above, expected result. And why you use pca.model > pcb.model? why > sign please explain little. thanks

Comment: Because you wrote in the question: "Result required as : model with the bigger number, model with the smaller number, ..." . Having the `>` sign makes sure that a) rows are not joined with themselves b) have the greated model number on the left and smaller on the right.

Comment: The last rows for me are: `1260 |  1232 |   500 |  32` and `1260 |  1233 |   500 |  32`. Mind the second model 1232 <-> 1233 difference. If I missed something please let me know but I don't see duplicated rows.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite the same format, but achieves the goal:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT model ORDER BY model) AS 'model(s)',
       speed,
       ram
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY speed, ram;
```

Answer (score 0):

An yet another creative way:

```
select distinct a.model, b.model, a.speed, a.ram from TblComputer a join TblComputer b on a.speed = b.speed and a.ram=b.ram where a.model > b.model
 union
 select distinct b.model, a.model, a.speed, a.ram from TblComputer a join TblComputer b on a.speed = b.speed and a.ram=b.ram where b.model > a.model
```

Here's my data:

```
create table TblComputer
(
    model int,
    speed int,
    ram int
)

insert into TblComputer(model, speed, ram) values (1121,   600, 128) 
insert into TblComputer(model, speed, ram) values (1121,   600, 128) 
insert into TblComputer(model, speed, ram) values (1121,   750, 128 )
insert into TblComputer(model, speed, ram) values (1232,   450,  32 )
insert into TblComputer(model, speed, ram) values (1232,   450,  64 )
insert into TblComputer(model, speed, ram) values (1232,   500,  32 )
insert into TblComputer(model, speed, ram) values (1232,   500,  64 )
insert into TblComputer(model, speed, ram) values (1233,   500,  64 )
insert into TblComputer(model, speed, ram) values (1233,   750, 128 )
insert into TblComputer(model, speed, ram) values (1233,   800, 128 )
insert into TblComputer(model, speed, ram) values (1233,   900, 128 )
insert into TblComputer(model, speed, ram) values (1260,   500,  32 )
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.model, b.model, a.speed, a.ram
FROM pc a, pc b
WHERE a.speed=b.speed AND a.ram=b.ram AND a.model>b.model
```